# Error while compiling the project with npm

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, lerna

I am trying to get a project running and when I execute the `npm install` it installs all the dependencies.
But after that I try to execute `npm run compile` and it gives me an error.

Here is the log file for better understanding the error.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/Users/roxhens/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/roxhens/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.13.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle jsonforms-tooling-common@0.0.1~prebuild: jsonforms-tooling-common@0.0.1
6 info lifecycle jsonforms-tooling-common@0.0.1~build: jsonforms-tooling-common@0.0.1
7 verbose lifecycle jsonforms-tooling-common@0.0.1~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle jsonforms-tooling-common@0.0.1~build: PATH: /Users/roxhens/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/roxhens/Desktop/GitHub/jsonforms-tooling/jsonforms-tooling-common/node_modules/.bin:/Users/roxhens/Desktop/GitHub/jsonforms-tooling/jsonforms-tooling-common/node_modules/.bin:/Users/roxhens/Desktop/GitHub/jsonforms-tooling/node_modules/.bin:/Users/roxhens/Desktop/GitHub/node_modules/.bin:/Users/roxhens/Desktop/node_modules/.bin:/Users/roxhens/node_modules/.bin:/Users/node_modules/.bin:/node_modules/.bin:/Users/roxhens/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/bin:/Users/roxhens/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/roxhens/Desktop/GitHub/jsonforms-tooling/node_modules/.bin:/Users/roxhens/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin
9 verbose lifecycle jsonforms-tooling-common@0.0.1~build: CWD: /Users/roxhens/Desktop/GitHub/jsonforms-tooling/jsonforms-tooling-common
10 silly lifecycle jsonforms-tooling-common@0.0.1~build: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run compile' ]
11 silly lifecycle jsonforms-tooling-common@0.0.1~build: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle jsonforms-tooling-common@0.0.1~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: jsonforms-tooling-common@0.0.1 build: `npm run compile`
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/roxhens/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/roxhens/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
14 verbose pkgid jsonforms-tooling-common@0.0.1
15 verbose cwd /Users/roxhens/Desktop/GitHub/jsonforms-tooling/jsonforms-tooling-common
16 verbose Darwin 18.2.0
17 verbose argv "/Users/roxhens/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/bin/node" "/Users/roxhens/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v10.13.0
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error jsonforms-tooling-common@0.0.1 build: `npm run compile`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the jsonforms-tooling-common@0.0.1 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

This is the `package.json` in the project root directory.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "lerna": "lerna",
    "coveralls": "ts-jest --coverage && cat ./tests/coverage/lcov.info | coveralls",
    "postinstall": "npm run lernabootstrap && npm run lernainstall",
    "lernainstall": "lerna exec --no-bail --npm-ci-mode -- npm run custominstall",
    "lernabootstrap": "lerna bootstrap --npm-ci-mode --ignore-scripts",
    "compile": "lerna run build",
    "lint": "lerna run lint"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.11",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.10",
    "coveralls": "^3.0.2",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "lerna": "^3.4.3",
    "rimraf": "2.6.3",
    "ts-jest": "^23.10.4",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "tslint-react": "^3.6.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6",
    "vscode": "^1.1.21"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@jsonforms/core": "^2.0.12",
    "simple-git": "^1.107.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Lets see package.json

Comment: @stever I updated the post

Comment: Sorry wish I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still cannot find the reason why that error, but I managed to fix it by deleting the files and cloning the repository again.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you're trying to build the following:

https://github.com/eclipsesource/jsonforms-tooling

When trying to build libraries found on GitHub (or elsewhere), you can look at how they build it on their CI or look at some other scripts. It seems that for this particular lib, their `.travis.yml` does not contain everything to make it work on all platforms.

I fiddled with it for a bit and running these (rather straightforward) commands from the root folder should solve your problem:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/eclipsesource/jsonforms-tooling
cd jsonforms-tooling
npm install
npm run compile
```

Comment: The problem still is the same.

Comment: @RoxhensM. indeed! I updated the answer with the steps to make it work (tested on MacOs)

Comment: Thank you for your time. The branch which I am actually trying to set up is this: https://github.com/TheZoker/jsonforms-tooling/tree/feat/yo-basic-project

Comment: It doesn't change the nature of the answer: `npm install && npm run compile` from the root folder (not from jsonforms-tooling-common)

Comment: I understand. But, it is still the same error and I cannot figure out what causes the error. Are you able to compile from the branch in the above comment?

Comment: Yes it does work `git clone -b feat/yo-basic-project https://github.com/TheZoker/jsonforms-tooling.git && cd jsonforms-tooling && npm install && npm run compile`